# Clone HDD with dd

Tags: linux, filesystems, dd

I wanna clone a hdd but without loosing data from /home

My current scheme is:

```
[root@ns1 ~]# lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0   512G  0 disk
├─sda1                8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2                8:2    0   511G  0 part
  ├─centos_ns1-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos_ns1-swap 253:1    0   7.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos_ns1-home 253:2    0 453.1G  0 lvm  /home
```

The target HDD is broken and I wanna copy everything except the /home content ( including partition schema or whatever metadata /home have ) just to leave the /home content intact on the old hdd. Both hdd have ( the damaged hdd had* ) the same partition schema and the os was installed with the same options, the hdd space is the same

```
[root@ns1 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 549.8 GB, 549755813888 bytes, 1073741824 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000b809e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200  1073741823   535821312   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos_ns1-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos_ns1-swap: 8455 MB, 8455716864 bytes, 16515072 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Disk /dev/mapper/centos_ns1-home: 486.5 GB, 486530875392 bytes, 950255616 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I ended up with this

dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb count=?? bs=512 conv=notrunc,noerror

But how can I find the exact number to count before the data in /home begin?

---

The problem is that I tried to live migrate a vm from a node to another, the migration fail and the main hdd fail. I tried to boot CentOs > Troubleshooting but I got the "ou don't have any linux partitionsY". Then I tried in many ways to recover some data but without success. Now I make the system again with the same options and I wanna copy everything from 0 till first block with user data in '/home' to keep the data from /home intact.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with the fact that you are using LVM, which makes it very difficult to do what you are attempting.

You ask **"how can I find the exact number to count before the data in /home begin"** -   You may not be able to do this.   Because LVM abstracts the disk from the partition, your LVM could be in multiple parts.   You may be able to get some useful data about the "physical extents" - ie the underlying blocks by using vgdisplay to see the block side, and then  "lvdisplay -m" to see the extents are not in use.  That said, trying to data recovery this way would seem to me like a recipe for disaster.

While 500 gig is not tiny, it is not massive, and your best bet might be to clone the whole disk, then delete /home on the target.   Rather then using dd, might I suggest using ddrescue - this is designed to handle data recovery, gives you a progress indication and progress log it can use to allow you to stop and restart the process.

Getting to a point I'd be very unhappy with - and would not try without strong backups (and indeed I've never tried it myself and it is likely pointless here), you could also attempt to back up the LVM partition information, destroy /home, do your backup [ but this is where your issue will come in ] and then restore the lvm partition information using lvdump  (https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-lvm-backing-up-volume-group-metadata/  - btw, this creates human readable backups of your LVM setup - so useful for working out blocks as well maybe ?)

Comment: I can't explain how from a migration the whole disk is gone, no partition nor at least something exist there ... btw, it's a freeNas zvol and I didn't take a snapshoot before migrating :(

Comment: now I'm trying with testdisk ...

Comment: That's messed up. If it really is a zvol please ignore what I wrote.  That said I am skeptical - a zvol is associated with ZFS, but you appear to be using LVM.

Comment: it's a zvol on a FreeNas zfs pool wich is connected over iscsi to a proxmox vm. the output above is from vm, so only the hdd is store in freenas as zvol

Comment: It would have helped tremendously if you'd explained that in the first place. You've gone from a relatively simple (but still tricky) scenario to a pretty much impossible one.